# ImportError: No module named _winreg, Installing pypiwin32==219 on MacOS X

Tags: python

I am trying to install `pypiwin32==219` in my virtual environment from a requirements.txt file.
 
**requirements.txt**

```
pypiwin32==219
```

I have setup a virtualenv `denv` in which I am working.

```
(denv) Nehas-MacBook-Pro:dash_pdf neha$ pip install -r requirements.txt
```

I got this traceback error:

```
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/private/var/folders/_y/g09fpxn13xq7z6ptmq3095dm0000gn/T/pip-install-7zp59n5n/pypiwin32/setup.py", line 121
    print "Building pywin32", pywin32_version
                           ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print("Building pywin32", pywin32_version)?
```

which really is a python version issue so I switched to the command:

```
(denv) Nehas-MacBook-Pro:dash_pdf neha$ pip2 install -r requirements.txt
```

upon which I get this traceback error:

```
Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/2b/ca/5c086c18de8f70222787b3e824e755b68d99272531522e77bb381d4f60c8/pypiwin32-219.zip
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/private/var/folders/_y/g09fpxn13xq7z6ptmq3095dm0000gn/T/pip-install-KEpN56/pypiwin32/setup.py", line 83, in <module>
    import _winreg
ImportError: No module named _winreg
```

I googled some and I found that `_winreg` required Windows. No way I can get `pypiwin32==219` to work on MacOS? Or any other modules I can use with the same functionality?

Comment: Pywin32 = Python extensions for Microsoft Windows .... Why do you need to install this on your MAC/expect it to work?

Comment: I am working on a handed-over project and I got to continue it from there. And many of the files in it have dependencies on `pypiwin32`. I did understand that the module is windows specific. Any way I can get around this?

Comment: The code must be developed in a windows environment and for that the prev. developer used whatever he used. Now I need to get around this issue. Only possible solution is to shift to Windows?

Comment: Well, since pywin32 is a wrapper around the Windows API, I think your two options are: go through project and evaluate the places it is used and judge if it can be rewritten in an OS independent fashion (probably unnecessary work, since the final application is to run on Windows only anyway?) or use a VM with windows for the development

Comment: Thanks @FlyingTeller for your suggestions. I am gonna go ahead and try using a VM

Answer (score 0):

i suggest, that winreg is only for Windows